# Opensource Sip клиент

Tags: c#, c++, opensource, sip

Надо сделать SipClient с плюшками под Винду. Хотела взять какой нибудь опенсурс и допилить. Из нормальных нашла только MicroSip (с++). Думала разберусь, но сами сырцы в проект никак не собрать, похоже разработчики не выложили всех библиотек. Вот и обращаюсь к сообществу с просьбой помочь знает кто открытый SipClient который можно нормально скомпилить. Лучше конечно на Net, но если нет на Net - на чем угодно. Буду очень благодарна.

Comment: http://www.ekiga.org/

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь https://github.com/darkworks/sipek2. Готовый проект, написан на C# (Win Forms). Используется библиотека PJSIP и обертка для .NET под нее Sipek

Answer (score 1):

День добрый. Лучшее что есть:
[sipsorcery](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery)
По крайней мере этот проект поддерживается.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/314886)

Comment: @freim [Что делать, когда просят ссылки, а потом получают ссылки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1638/213987) - отвечать "выглядит нормально".  — [из очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/314886)